Kusto multiple summarize in single query
I have a device_event table and I'm trying out following query :
device_events
| where orgid = 1
| summarize failedEvents = countif(name=='failure'),
           successEvents = countif(name=='success'),
           p95EventTime = percentile(toreal(event_time), 95) by orgid
| summarize fallbackCountByCity = countif(name=='fallback') by cityid

But kusto doesn't allow this. How do I achieve this ? Or do I have to write 2 separate queries for this ?

Hi! After your first summarize is executed, the only fields you have left are "failedEvents", "successEvents", and "p95EventTime". So when your next summarize is executed, the field cityid simply is not available. You will have to make the first query include that it it's result for this to work :)


Kusto multiple summarize in single query

Yes, Instead of multiple summarize in single query you need to write two separate queries and join the query results by using join as you can see in the below query.
let Sales = datatable(Region:string, Product:string, Quantity:int, Revenue:double) [
    "East", "Product A", 100, 5000.00,
    "East", "Product B", 150, 7500.00,
    "West", "Product A", 120, 6000.00,
    "West", "Product B", 130, 6500.00,
];

let QuantitySummary = Sales
| summarize TotalQuantity = sum(Quantity) by Region;

let RevenueSummary = Sales
| summarize TotalRevenue = sum(Revenue) by Region;

QuantitySummary
| join kind=inner (RevenueSummary) on Region
| project Region, TotalQuantity, TotalRevenue

Output:

Multiple summarize in single query is not supported in kql as you can see below it throws an error:
StormEvents
| where InjuriesDirect > 0
| summarize by EventType
| summarize by State

Output:


yes but this doesn't answer my case because in my case summarize by in two statements is different. So the question was about how to join these two ?
